# Extracting HTML Table in Beautiful Soup, Getting Repeated Elements

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Trying web scraping for the second time, and running into a strange error.

The end result I am going for is to scrap the table and put each row into a SQL table, but this has 90s style nested tables, no divisions, and no classes. I've read about using structure, but I don't know enough to know how to do that. I've been curious about whether I can start at a certain line as "structure", but that has limitations as well.

Current challenge is that this code picks up repeated elements and ignores others before moving to the next row.

```
import bs4
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'http://www.texasregionalradio.com/top100.asp'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
table_soup = page_soup

# Limit the amount of HTML grabbed by Soup
#table_soup = page_soup.findAll("table", {"class":"sample"})

# Trying to grab cells from each row. Randomly chose [8:10] but I      don't know what they are selecting or why.

for row in table_soup.findAll("tr")[8:10]:
    for cell in row.findAll("td"):
        print(cell.text)
```

Results in:

```
12  
2    
1     

PUT MY MONEY ON THAT / Independent   (1) Weeks at #1  
Curtis Grimes
PUT MY MONEY ON THAT / Independent   (1) Weeks at #1  
Curtis Grimes
PUT MY MONEY ON THAT / Independent   (1) Weeks at #1  
Curtis Grimes
```

Also, I just learned that .text can format the unicode so I don't get strange strings, and I'm very happy about it, and don't have anyone to share it with who would care. So, that's you. Thanks for your help. :)

Q1: How can isolate the table best with this mess?
Q2: Why are elements missing?
Q3: What are elements repeated?

**Edit**:

Some results improved by switching parsers to "html5lib":

```
12  
2    
1     


PUT MY MONEY ON THAT / Independent   (1) Weeks at #1  
Curtis Grimes
PUT MY MONEY ON THAT / Independent   (1) Weeks at #1  
Curtis Grimes
2192 
1967 
+225 
88%   
1   
PUT MY MONEY ON THAT / Independent   (1) Weeks at #1  
Curtis Grimes
```

Answer (score 0):

That page displays the items you're looking for as a table-within-a-table, like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>DESIRED TEXT HERE</td>
```

The desired `<td>` element is a child (or grandchild) of both the outer table `<tr>` and the inner table `<tr>`, so your search finds the same `<td>` element multiple times.

Comment: Thank you. What do I change so that it only finds it once?

Comment: The inner table has `class="inner"`, so you might be able to restrict your initial search to only tables of that class.